# Nodemailer - DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, nodemailer

I need to create a script that send a mail once a day using a gmail account. I've used nodemailer and I have this simple test code

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    //secure: true,
    //port: 465,
    auth: {
        user: 'myuser@companyworkspace.com',
        pass: 'mypassword'
    }
})

let mailOptions = {
    from: 'bruno.paolillo@ohspa.it', // sender address
    to: 'bruno.paolillo@ohspa.it', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Test email', // Subject line
    text: 'this is some text', //, // plaintext body
    html: '<b>Hello world </b>' // You can choose to send an HTML body instead
}

transport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if( error ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        return true;
    };
});
```

I've noticed that I will always get this error when I try to run the script using `node index.js`

```
(node:20496) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Is there any problem into the code or it's a nodemailer bug?Is there any alternative?

Comment: Have a look at this open issue and the comment by andris9 (nodemailer author): https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/1587

Comment: So what can be a fix for this? I dont't know what a punycode is

Comment: You could use a different npm package, or, you can probably ignore the warning for now and hope that Nodemailer fixes the issue (after all, Punycode has been deprecated since node v7 & we're now in v21). Punycode used to be an [inbuilt module](https://nodejs.org/api/punycode.html) within node but has since been deprecated and could be removed in future versions of node. Nodemailer is using this deprecated version which is what's giving you the warning.

Comment: I've used in past nodemailer and this problem didn't occur. I've used the `mail-composer` module. I hope that the team will fix this. At t he moment I will opt to use blat and call it using spawn of node js

Comment: I'm guessing that node added this deprecation warning as part of node v21 so it wasn't seen before.

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into the same issue. You need to downgrade your Node Version to 20.9.0.

Comment: downgrade is a painful process propably the best solution is to wait until nodemailer update the source code

Comment: Useful [MacOS homebrew node downgrading answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/207883/81395).

Comment: How will we fix this once Node 21 or Node 22 become the LTS version that we should be using??? Why would they put in a deprecation warning for something that the person seeing the warning can't address in any way?

Comment: @AndrewKoster: To communicate to package owners the need to stop relying on `punycode` in node itself.  Upstream breakage is frustrating but part of the deal we accept when we benefit from functionality provided by dependencies.

Comment: So the goal is to annoy the end users of Yarn until they petition the maintainers of Yarn to stop using the thing that Node deprecated? Seems like a weird workflow.

Answer (score 0):

solution that worked for me:
npm install punycode --save

and then in node_modules go to the directory tr46 > index.js

Replace this:
`const punycode = require('punycode');`
With this:
`const punycode = require('punycode/');`

basically just add a trailing forward slash

Comment: when you remove node_modules and do npm install again, it will forget your changes made inside the node_modules directory

Comment: yes it will but it's for me to run on my local machine the changes are not made in the actual codebase so when someone uses this repo then it will act accordingly to their node version the problem here is that the error occurs to causing the new version of node is not supported with Punycode you have to downgrade your node to work it.